# How to show browser's default theme background in html?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the background of a HTML body the same as a browser's current default background? i.e., if I set my Chrome with a space theme, can I have the same space image as the background for my web site?

The goal is to allow users see their own theme merged with the web page.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. You'd have a load of problems getting it to work in different browsers and all browsers are different, maybe give users an option to change the colour themselves using a swatch or something

Comment: @trainmania100 thanks, I think that will be the only way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this.

Webpages are rendered in an opaque viewport.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting that, just wanted to know if is just my ignorance :)